# which to use, Payment Preferred or Payment preference

Tags: phrase-usage

i am developing a cart, in the order placing section, there is an option to choose whether to use online payment and cash on delivery

I have doubt which one to use

Payment Preferred or Payment preference

Comment: "Preferred payment method" would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In England, preferred payment method is often used.'Payment preferred' may infer that the payment may optional! Payment preference could be used, but would be most often used in an informal conversation.

Comment: I am not sure to upvote this answer because of my limited knowledge

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan a fair comment. I would say that you should stay with preferred payment method.